# How to pass a list a parameter in LISP

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, factorial

I am currently trying to implement a factorial function for a class.
My function takes one argument **n**, and lists the factorials from 0, 1, 2, ... **n**.

This is what I currently have:

This is the function I will be calling, right now it just returns the factorial of **N**:

```
(defun factor3 (N)
    (apply #'* (loop :for n :from 1 :below (+ 1 N) :collect n))   
)
```

This is a helper function that returns a list of integers from 1 until **num**. Acc, when called initially, takes **NIL** as an empty list to accumulate the values:

```
(defun my-seq (num acc) 
    (if (eq num 0) 
        acc
        (my-seq (- num 1) (cons num acc)))
```

Each of these functions act as expected individually, now I want to apply the **factor3** function to each member of the list that is returned from **my-seq**, and my professor has hinted at two keywords:

- Using `apply`
- Using `mapcar`

However, when I call

`(mapcar 'factor3 '(my-seq 5 NIL))`

I get

`*** - +: MY-SEQ is not a number`

So, I try saving the returned list from **my-seq** to a variable **b**, then I call

`(mapcar 'factor3 'b)`

And I get

`*** - MAPCAR: A proper list must not end with B`

I have tried many different variable names and I get the same error. How should I implement this code?

It seems all I need to do is pass the return as a parameter, but there are such limited resourced on the internet for the LISP language.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Don't quote `(my-seq 5 NIL)`.

Comment: You obviously know how to use `LOOP`, why don't you use it in `my-seq`? `(loop for i from 1 to num collect i)`

Comment: don't use EQ to compare numbers, use EQL or =

Comment: What is the difference between factorial of 3 and of 4? Thus if you loop a variable from 1 to n and have a variable where you multiply and accumulate that value you'll s end up with a list `(1 2 6 24 ...)`

Comment: Your `factor3` wastfully builds a list. Try this: `(defun factor3 (n) (loop for i from 1 to n   for acc = 1 then (* acc i)   finally (return acc)))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't quote expressions and variables that should be evaluated.

```
(mapcar 'factor3 (my-seq 5 NIL))
```

or

```
(defvar b (my-seq 5 NIL))
(mapcar 'factor3 b)
```

Answer (score 2):

See the difference between evaluation of a quoted list and just the list:

**QUOTED**

```
CL-USER 4 > '(factor3 42)
(FACTOR3 42)

CL-USER 5 > (describe '(factor3 42))

(FACTOR3 42) is a LIST
0      FACTOR3
1      42
```

**NON-QUOTED**:

```
CL-USER 6 > (factor3 42)
1405006117752879898543142606244511569936384000000000
```

**Summary**

If you want to compute a value, then you have to leave the form to be evaluated non-quoted.

Answer (score 0):

i think this code is must usefull

```
(defun factor (n)
   (labels ((built-in-factor (x)
             (if (< x 2)
                 1
                 (* x (built-in-factor (1- x))))))
     (if (numberp n)
         (mapcar #'built-in-factor (loop for i from 1 to n collect i))
         '(oops your value is not number))))
```